# If I'm not using a GUI program, how do I know how much traffic has gone through my tor relay?

Tags: linux, tor

If I'm not using a GUI program, how do I know how much traffic has gone through my tor relay? I'm on Linux, and run tor as a system service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [arm](https://www.atagar.com/arm/) you can monitor traffic information. Install this program and simply run it in terminal without any command line options, and you'll see realtime traffic in a TUI interface:

[image]

Comment: That's not really much of an improvement. Can you please show an example of how to use the command for your specific case? Some screenshot would also be nice. Thanks.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for pointing out the confusion. This is really the simplest kind of command. Simply run it and the traffic is shown.

Comment: This answer still needs the relevant information

Comment: I see, I added a screenshot for you. Thanks for explaining.